# how to download .jad File and its related .cod File on bb Client

Tags: blackberry

I have .jad files and its related .cod files and i have uploaded it to the server whenever i hit the link form my blackberry bb browser it opens the file in the browser.

i want to upload apps to my server and whenever the link is hit from bb browser it automatically start downloading and  install the app

what should i do... i have read the forum in which it says call a .htaccess file to app directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Likely your web server is not sending the correct MIME types for .jad and .cod files, as documented in [Installing BlackBerry Java Applications Using the Web Browser](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/admin/deliverables/18777/Installing_BB_Java_Apps_using_web_browser_629161_11.jsp). How you do this depends on your web server, but for Apache web servers you can do this by following the instructions in [How to Setup an Apache Web Server to Deliver BlackBerry OTA Applications](http://www.blackberryinsight.com/2008/07/08/howto-setup-an-apache-webserver-to-deliver-blackberry-ota-applications/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I have achieved it i have used the mime type...

```
AddType text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor jad
AddType application/vnd.rim.cod cod
AddType application/java-archive jar
AddType audio/adpcm adp
```

in `.htaccess` file and place it with my app and when i hit the direct link i get the app downloaded to my blackberry from bb browser....